# Execute Ant task on save in IDEA

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

How to execute Ant task on every document save in Intellij IDEA?

If you right-click on some task you can see Execute on -> After Compilation,
but I want to execute my task after each document save, how can I do it?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  What Ant task are you executing?

Comment: I'd like to use it in my javascript project

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible? This feature will kill your computer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible and for a good reason. IDEA saves files automatically on many occasions and it would make your machine unusable.